# Can code in a dynamically loaded Bundle access its own Info.plist file?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In a macOS App I am loading bundles as plugins during runtime.
I would like the "plugins" to provide a version string and it would be nice to use the Info.plist for that.

The problem is, that any call to `Bundle(class: Pluginclass...) will at runtime result in the Bundle of the application loading the bundle (as there is no such thing as a "bundle" for the code that is loaded from it)

Is there any way this would be possible?

I do not want to provide a version as a property of the plugin's class, but really use the Info.plist file.

I could also wrap any loaded plugin in the host application that loads its bundle, and read the Info.plist there, but I'd rather do this inside the plugin (or rather the superclass they all derive from).

Comment: "bundle for the code that is loaded from it": `Bundle(for: type(of: self))`

Comment: You say, "I am loading bundles as plugins".  If you're referencing a bundle at that point, can't you use it to find the plist rather than trying to get the bundle again later?

Comment: @shallowThought As I tried to make clear, `self` is already part of the application's bundle when it is loaded. So this will always return the application

Comment: Wait... are you **actually** loading Bundles (capital B) to instantiate your plug-ins using `my_bundle = Bundle.init(url:...)` or `my_bundle = Bundle.init(path:...)` and then `my_bundle.load()`?  If so you should be able to use the `infoDictionary` for that `Bundle` to get at the `info.plist`.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, this is of course possible (and is what I am doing now), but implies that the plugin loader needs to extract this. I'd much rather have the plugin provide a property as I mentioned.

Comment: @ScottThompson See my previous comment. Yes that is how I am doing it now, but I would rather do it inside the plugin, and not the loader.

Comment: Compile the bundle identifier into the bundle's code and use the bundle identifier to look up the bundle for the plugin.  That way the plugin code will be able to find it's own bundle.

Comment: @ScottThompson Mhm, now that's a novel approach :). If that would work it wouldn't really be "pretty" though and actually makes me wonder if I am asking for something that's just plain stupid and/or pointless.

Comment: The unusual bit is that you say your plugin's class is defined in the main application bundle.  I would expect that the plugin's superclass is defined in the application, but the plugin would define a specific subclass of that which you could use to get back to the bundle's plugin.  But you said that is not the case.  The other ways to get to a bundle, then, are by path, or by identifier.

Comment: Yes, I meant the superclass. Sry for being vague here (actually the plugin's superclass is defined in a separate framework in Obj-C, as the loader can't handle casting to Swift classes/protocols)

Comment: Can the loader provide the plugin with a bundle reference for it to use?  (Since it can't use it until after it's loaded anyway.)

Comment: @PhillipMills That's a nice idea! Gotta think about it for a while how that would work without the plugin author needing to know... If you can sketch it out as an answer, I'll accept it